# R.Net - After disposing of the R engine, we cannot reinitialize nor reuse it

Tags: r.net

I am creating a web application and calling r file through R.NET. The issue is if we use engine.dispose(), the next time we run the application it throws error as "Engine is shutdown, cannot restart it"

The code works fine if I do not dispose engine, but it consumes lot of memory on multiple executions.

Sample code below:

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();

REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

engine.Evaluate("//Some code here or calling external r file //");

engine.dispose();
```

Thanks,
Prajwal Dsilva